# Epson xp-410 drivers

Tags: software-installation

I'm on the latest ubuntu iteration, 13.10 I believe, and I cant find any drivers for my printer.

When i tried to use the generic drivers it just prints out symbols and when i try to use other epson drivers it will print in weird colors.

So my question is this, are there ways to get the drivers for Ubuntu or will I just have to use windows whenever I want to print something?

Its an Epson xp-410

Answer (score 2):

Download the deb driver from:

The 32 bit drivers are:

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/main/binary-i386/epson-inkjet-printer-201303w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb

The 64 bit drivers are:

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/main/binary-amd64/epson-inkjet-printer-201303w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

I have an XP-540. I had the same problem with the printer only printing boring ASCII characters ... in the leftmost column only, leaving the rest of the page white. This worked for me:

```
sudo aptitude install printer-driver-escpr
```

After that, this driver appeared: `EPSON XP-530 Series , Epson Inkjet Printer Driver (ESC/P-R) for Linux` — which seems to work fine, although I have an XP-540 not XP-530.

(Before that, I also installed `imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-16.04-1.3.20.x64.deb.tar.gz`, which I downloaded from here: `http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php?version=1.3.20#ubuntu`, and I also: `sudo aptitude install lsb` — not sure which (if any) of these things were actually needed. They did not make the printer work.)