# EPSON XP-342 won't print

Tags: drivers, software-installation, printing, epson

I just installed EPSON XP-342 printer. I can copy, but it won't print. What am I missing?

Comment: Which ubuntu version are you using? Try to install the Epson drivers for your version.

Comment: Hi,

I am using 16-04 LTS

Comment: One more, how do I do that? I'v try to do updates, but I guess I'm not doing something right. Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to the site. I would suggest editing your question to include anymore information that you can. This would help people resolve your issue. The Ubuntu version has already been added, but any error messages or logs would help.

Comment: Here's another answer to a similar / the-same question: https://askubuntu.com/a/916645/48382

Answer (score 3):

Delete the existing epson icon in the PRINTERS folder; if not working; (right-click and select DELETE)

One generally starts [here on the official download page](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX) for Epson drivers

I can point you [directly to this page](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=55539&DSCCHK=5ef6ec128765534a989152269045f12fc58077f2)

For Ubuntu 64bit, you need `epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.13-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`. As you click to download, the query box will ask you if want to open the file: click <kbd>yes</kbd>, as that opens the Gdebi installer so which will install the package.

For a printer, you need to

1. install the drivers
2. register the printer

The latter may not automatically happen: an entry should be created for you in the PRINTERS folder, if not you need to do it manually

Comment: Thank you very, very much!!! I can print now...but I can't scan yet. Can you help me with that, please?

Comment: please [edit] your answer in response to comments